# Fail to upload file size 0 with chunking option enabled

Tags: upload, fine-uploader

I can't upload file with size 0.  I have enabled chunking option.  Is there a limit of what the file size has to be?  Please see below error for more info.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shift' of undefinedchunked.nextPart @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4056chunked.sendNext @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4076upload.now @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4493upload.maybeSendDeferredFiles @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4446upload.maybeDefer @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4420upload.start @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4501qq.extend.upload @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:4523qq.basePrivateApi._uploadFile @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:3108qq.basePublicApi.uploadStoredFiles @ s3.fineuploader-5.0.3-2.js:1822

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying you want to upload an empty file? Why would you want to do that? In fact, this is usually prohibited and caught by the validation logic by Fine Uploader, although [this validation was briefly broken but fixed in version 5.2.0](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/1381). I'm guessing you have an older version.
There is [an open feature request to allow empty files to pass through](https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/903), but that is fairly low priority and is not scheduled for any near future release.

Comment: It's a test case which customer accidentally has an empty file in addition to other upload files.  I am using an older version.  However, I will definitely update to 5.2.0 to avoid this exception.  Thank you.